# Why do mounted file systems without ACL options still respect POSIX ACLs?

Tags: linux, redhat, filesystems, mount

According to `mount`, the file system does not have the ACL option:

```
$ mount
/dev/mapper/sys_vg-root_lv on / type ext3 (rw)
```

However, I could still `setfacl` and `getfacl` on this file system. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the ACL option.

I'm using RHEL5 on this system.

Comment: Possibly this will be a interview Question, Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RHEL, ACLs are enabled by default for any filesystems configured at install-time. This can be verified with `tune2fs -l <device>`.

Any filesystems created post-install must either have the `acl` mount option in /etc/fstab, or have it hard-set with `tune2fs -o acl <device>`.

Comment: Ah nice to know. `tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/sys_vg-root_lv  | grep -i 'acl'` showed that it was part of the default mount options.

Answer (score 1):

ACLs are enabled by default on some filesystems like ext3, ext4, and xfs on modern Linux distributions.